# Select matching rows where two columns reference each other

Tags: mysql

I have a table called 'friends' where 'followed' is the id of the user who has been followed and 'follower' is the id of the user who has done the following, set out like this:

```
id  |  followed  |  follower
------------------------------
1   |     34     |    67
2   |     89     |    65
3   |     67     |    34
4   |     51     |    12
5   |     78     |    18
6   |     18     |    78
```

I can run the queries which display who a user is following and a query for who is following a user easily enough, but what I want to be able to do is run a single query which shows where the friendship is reciprocated, e.g:

```
SELETCT * FROM friends WHERE
 -- follower and followed have followed each other
```

So for the above, this would return the id 1 and 5 (or 3 and 6).

How can I achieve this matching in a single query?

Comment: Do you mean - this would return the id 1 and **3** (or **5** and 6)?

Comment: Well id's 1 and 3 are the same because each user is following the other, if that makes sense, so I just need to return one or the other. The sames applies to users 78 and 18.

Comment: I mean that in your post you write `So for the above, this would return the id 1 and 5 (or 3 and 6).`

Comment: I'm sorry z, just struggled to explain it briefly. Thanks for your answer - just trying it out now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7a1f9/10)

Just use join with the following condition

```
 select * from 
 temp t1 join temp t2 
     where t1.follower=t2.followed 
     and t1.followed=t2.follower
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Select f1.id, f2.id FROM friends as f1
JOIN friends as f2
ON f1.followed = f2.follower AND f1.follower = f2.followed
```

Comment: should be "join friends as f2"

Answer (score 0):

Of course this can be done.  SQL is quite powerful.  Here is an example of doing it using the `exists` clause with a correlated subquery:

```
select f.*
from follows f
where exists (select 1
              from follows f2
              where f2.followed = f.follower and f2.follower = f.followed
             );
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use or query below

```
SELECT *
FROM `friends`
WHERE (
`follower` = '34'
OR followed = '34'
)
```